# Lorentz force on current

Tags: electromagnetism

I've found many explanations describing the magnetic field created by moving charges.

Also I have found explanations regarding the force of a magnetic field on a moving charge (Lorentz force).

I have yet to see a combination of the two, which logically seem to be simultaneous effects.

Is it correct to assume that current induces a magnetic field which in turn creates a spiraling trajectory?  Is there a name for this?

Update:

I'm also reading that a changing magnetic field creates an electric field, but haven't quite figured out how that will affect the current. In the case of AC current, the frequently changing current creates a frequently changing magnetic field, which creates a frequently changing electric field..?!

Where does it end?

Comment: note that the magnetic field generated by a moving charge does not directly affect the charge itself. It can indirectly affect the charge, but a charge won't start spiraling due to the magnetic field it generates.

Comment: How do you know a charge doesn't effect itself?  In a current carrying wire, there are lots of charges.  Surely neighboring charges can effect eachother, so I'm not sure if it matters

Comment: Neighbouring charges can affect each other. But the generation of a magnetic field due to motion is a phenomenon of relativity. Relative to the charge itself, it is at rest in its own frame, so it does not see any magnetic field generated by it.